# undo the tokenization in python

Tags: python, text-mining

I would like to reverse the tokenization that I have applied to my data.

```
data = [['this', 'is', 'a', 'sentence'], ['this', 'is', 'a', 'sentence', '2']]
```

Expected output:

```
['this is a sentence', 'this is a sentence 2']
```

I tried to do this with the following code block:

```
from nltk.tokenize.treebank import TreebankWordDetokenizer
data_untoken= []
for i, text in enumerate(data):
    data_untoken.append(text)
    data_untoken = TreebankWordDetokenizer().detokenize(text)
```

But I have the following error

```
'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: `' '.join(data)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `join()`:

```
def untokenize(data):
    for tokens in data:
        yield ' '.join(tokens)


data = [['this', 'is', 'a', 'sentence'], ['this', 'is', 'a', 'sentence', '2']]
untokenized_data = list(untokenize(data))
```